# Slice of pointers to interface for MySQL queries abstractions

Tags: mysql, pointers, go, interface, slice

I am trying to abstract my uses of my MySQL database and I'm stuck on a error.

There is the object I will take as example:

```
package models

// Product : The Product's model
type Product struct {
    ID         int
    Name       string
    Price      int
    PictureURL string
}
```

I'm going to try to retrieve the Product `id = 1` in my database. For that, let's say that I already have a connection to my database which is represented by the next variable:

```
var databaseMySQL *sql.DB
```

In order to query my database, I am using this function:

```
// QueryMySQL query our MySQL database
func QueryMySQL(sqlquery model.SQLQuery) model.Status {

    // prepare the query
    stmtOut, err := databaseMySQL.Prepare(sqlquery.Query)
    if err != nil {
        return model.Status{Code: http.StatusInternalServerError, Error: err}
    }
    defer stmtOut.Close()

    // Run the query
    err = stmtOut.QueryRow(sqlquery.Args).Scan(sqlquery.Dest)
    if err != nil {
        return model.Status{Code: http.StatusInternalServerError, Error: err}
    } else {
        return model.Status{Code: http.StatusOK, Error: nil}
    }
}
```

The 2 models used over here are `SQLQuery` & `Status`.

```
package models

type SQLQuery struct {
    Query string
    Args  []interface{}
    Dest  []*interface{}
}
```

**`Status` just basically contains an `error` and an `int`.**

So, since `Scan()` as the following prototype `Scan func(dest ...interface{}) error`, I can pass a `[]*interface{}` as parameter.

If I'm right, then I should be able to get my **Dest**'s elements filled by `T` type element, and then cast/transform them into the types I need?

```
func GetProductByID(ID int) (model.Product, model.Status) {

    // "SELECT ID, Name, Price, PictureURL FROM Products WHERE ID = ?"
    var _product model.Product

    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    var dest []*interface{}
    append(dest, &_product.Name)
    append(dest, &_product.Price)
    append(dest, &_product.PictureURL)
    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM

    status := QueryMySQL(model.SQLQuery{
        Query: "SELECT Name, Price, PictureURL FROM Products WHERE ID = ?",
        Args:  []interface{}{ID},
        Dest:  dest})

    return _product, model.Status{Code: http.StatusOK, Error: nil}
}
```

*PS: this function is just a basic test to try my logic*

However, I am getting an error:

> cannot use &_product.Name (type *string) as type *interface {} in append:
>       *interface {} is pointer to interface, not interface

To me, there is two errors:

- `cannot use &_product.Name (type *string) as type *interface {}`
- `*interface {} is pointer to interface, not interface`

First, why can't I use a interface to store my string?

Second, since I am passing a pointer on string, what's the matter with `interface{}`? it should be *interface{}, doesn't it?

---

### The correct code, thanks to David Budworth for his answer

In addition to the given code, you can pass slice as varargs like I did by adding `...` after your slice variable's name

*mysqlproduct.go*

```
// GetProductByID returns a Product based on a given ID
func GetProductByID(ID int) (model.Product, model.Status) {

    _product := model.Product{
        ID: ID}

    status := QueryMySQL(&model.SQLQuery{
        Query: "SELECT Name, Price, PictureURL FROM Products WHERE ID = ?",
        Args:  []interface{}{_product.ID},
        Dest:  []interface{}{&_product.Name, &_product.Price, &_product.PictureURL}})

    if status.Code != http.StatusOK {
        return _product, status
    }

    return _product, model.Status{Code: http.StatusOK, Error: ""}
}
```

*mysql.go*

```
// QueryMySQL query our MySQL database
func QueryMySQL(sqlquery *model.SQLQuery) model.Status {

    stmtOut, err := databaseMySQL.Prepare(sqlquery.Query)
    if err != nil {
        return model.Status{Code: http.StatusInternalServerError, Error: err.Error()}
    }
    defer stmtOut.Close()

    // Run the query
    err = stmtOut.QueryRow(sqlquery.Args...).Scan(sqlquery.Dest...)
    if err != nil {
        return model.Status{Code: http.StatusInternalServerError, Error: err.Error()}
    }
    defer stmtOut.Close()

    return model.Status{Code: http.StatusOK, Error: ""}
}
```

Comment: save yourself time, check this https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces can hold pointers.  There is rarely a reason to make a pointer to an interface.

If you change your type to []interface{} it should work.

If you really want pointers to interfaces, for some reason, you'd have to first store the field in an interface, then get a pointer to that.

ie:

```
var i interface{} = &_product.Name
append(dest, &i)
```

Comment: That's interesting, I will give it a try once I can. I'm a C dev so I understand pointers but I see interface {} as void *, and since the function store the results into varargs pointers, I was wondering if I could make it generic, you get me?

Comment: interface{} is more like `struct { ANY val, Type t }`  though, it can hold a value or a pointer to a value.   So, if you store a pointer in a plain old interface, the receiver (sql package) will be able to store stuff at that pointer.      And, since interfaces contain the type, the receiver can even allocate the memory to store the value.  so you can pass an empty pointer (though, in your example, the obj has been allocated)

Comment: Hoooo ok that make sense :) thank you for your answer :) my code doesn't return the data yet (product is just initialized but not filled with data) but you answer the main question so thanks 10000 times :)